# Leaflet: Auto Open Popup on each marker

Tags: javascript, popup, leaflet

I am follow [IvanSanchez's snakeIn](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim/blob/master/demo-group.gif) to draw each marker after each polyline.

The code has been modified such as

```
   var markers = [[63.5, 11],
    [40.5, -3.5],
    [51.5, -0.5],
    [52.3, 4.75],
    [39.5, -0.5]];

   var route = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

   var n = markers.length;

   for (var i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        var marker = new L.Marker(markers[i]);
        var line = new L.polyline([markers[i],markers[i+1]]);
        route.addLayer(marker);
        route.addLayer(line);
    };
   route.addLayer(new L.Marker(markers[n-1]));

   map.fitBounds(route.getBounds());
```

I have been trying to play with [Leaflet popup](http://leafletjs.com/#icon-popupanchor), where I can bindpopup for each marker. 
My question is how can I make each popup automatically open when its marker is drawn, then it will automatically close when the next marker is drawn, and so on...

Answer (score 2):

In Leaflet, every layer (including the markers) has an [`add` event](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#layer-add) which fires when it's added to the map.

Internally, the code for Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim removes and adds layers from a LayerGroup when a snaking animation runs; this means that layers which are snaking in will fire an `add` event.

Additionally, a `LayerGroup` (or `FeatureGroup`) running a snaking animation will fire a `snake` event every time a new layer is snaked in. Note, however, that this event does not have a reference to the just-snaked-in layer.

So something like:

```
marker1.on('add', function(){
    // Open popup for marker 1
});
```

You also say:

> then it will automatically close when the next marker is drawn,

First read the docs for [`L.Map.openPopup`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-openpopup), and then:

```
marker1.on('add', function(){
    map.openPopup( popupForMarker1 );
});
```

Comment: ---
<br/>
     var marker = new L.Marker(loc, {icon: allIcon});
       marker.on('add', function(){
          map.openPopup("my content");
        });
        var line = new L.polyline([loc, nextLoc]);
        route.addLayer(marker);
        route.addLayer(line);  
<br/>
---
It seems doesnt add any other marker, but only first marker is add and then stuck there. No popup show up also.

Comment: Can you make an example? It doesnt really work for me, and the SnakeIn function stopped.

Comment: It doesnt really work. I have been trying like what you said. None popup shows when each marker is drawn on snake in function.

Answer (score 1):

I asked myself the question and here is how I proceeded based on the answer of IvanSanchez and the doc https://leafletjs.com/index.html#map-openpopup

```
const marker = L.marker(L.latLng(this.location.lat, this.location.lng), {
  icon,
  title: this.location.name,
})
  .bindPopup(this.location.content)
  .on('add', function () {
    marker.openPopup();
  });
```